Bash regular expressions with the character classes are not matching
I am trying out the example 6.8 Testing with Regular Expressions from Bash Cookbook. I am reproducing the example here.
My folder contents are as,
$ ls
Ludwig Van Beethoven - 01 - Allegro.ogg
Ludwig Van Beethoven - 03 - Rondo - Allegro.ogg
Ludwig Van Beethoven - 02 - Adagio un poco mosso.ogg

Now I am renaming those files with this script,
for CDTRACK in *; do
  if [[ "$CDTRACK" =~ "([[:alpha:][:blank:]]*)- ([[:digit:]]*) - (.*)$" ]]; then                                                       
    mv "$CDTRACK" "Track${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  fi
done

It is not renaming any of those matching files. So, I tried to reduce the regex's complexity and do a simple pattern match as,

a=abcd
if [[ $a =~ "(.*)$" ]]; then      
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}                                                                                
fi

Now this is also not printing anything to the screen.
I have shell option extglob set to on.

Try after BASH_COMPAT=3.1 or shopt -s compat31 (or switch to zsh though there are better ways to do that in zsh). The idea is that in bash since 3.2, quoting doubles as regexp-escaping (though you need a recent version for that to work properly), so "." matches a lexical dot for instance. Storing the regex in a variable and do [[ $subject =~ $regex ]] (no quote around $regex) helps.

[[ $file == *.@(jpeg|jpg) ]] is not a regexp, that's a ksh glob operator. In zsh, alternation is just *.(jpg|jpeg) or here *.jp(e|)g (though you could also enable the ksh glob operators with set -o kshglob, IMO, zsh's are much better).

Adding my deleted comment since Stephane has answered it anyway.... referring Stephane's comment, switch to zsh though there are better ways to do that in zsh, there are many instances when zsh fails where bash succeeds. Like say, if [[ "my.jpeg" == *.@(jpg|jpeg) ]] ; then echo "hi" ; fi, bash prints echo whereas zsh  prints nothing.

In zsh here, I'd use its zmv: autoload zmv; zmv '*- (<1-99>) -*' 'Track$1' for instance.

Note that ([[:alpha:][:blank:]]*) is superfluous since it also matches the empty string and you're not using what it captures. Same for (.*)$ unless you want to exclude files which have non-characters after the - <number> -. Also note that [[:digit:]]* also matches the empty string. You likely want + instead of *.

To expand on Stephane's comment, read the whole paragraph that introduces the =~ operator.  The paragraph begins 'An additional binary operator, =~, is available, ...' and in the middle of the paragraph you find, 'If any part of the pattern is quoted, the quoted portion is matched literally.  This means every character in the  quoted  portion matches itself, instead of having any special pattern matching meaning.'  In Bash, don't quote the regex because it won't be interpreted as a regex.
